# I'm confused as to why the second activity isn't opening up?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been trying to open the second activity which is called "SecondActivity.java" but to no avail. It should be working with the ability to show a value the user will input and display it in the second activity. But the button just doesn't seem to do anything at all.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Spinner spnCurrency1, spnCurrency2;
    public Button btnSubmit;
    public Button btnDifferent;
    public EditText from;
    public TextView to;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnDifferent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDifferent);
        from = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.InputEditText);
        to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OutputTextView);


        spnCurrency1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCurrency1);
        List<String> lstCurrency1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstCurrency1.add("Euro");
        lstCurrency1.add("USD");
        lstCurrency1.add("Pound");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstCurrency1);
        dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnCurrency1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);


        spnCurrency2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCurrency2);
        List<String> lstCurrency2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstCurrency2.add("Euro");
        lstCurrency2.add("USD");
        lstCurrency2.add("Pound");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lstCurrency2);
        dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnCurrency2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int index1 = spnCurrency1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int index2 = spnCurrency2.getSelectedItemPosition();
        float value = Float.parseFloat(from.getText().toString());

        float ratio[] = {0.9f, 1.0f, 0.78f};
        float result = value / ratio[index1] * ratio[index2];

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSubmit:
                to.setText(result + "");
                break;
            case R.id.btnDifferent:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Result", result);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, does `btnSubmit ` click works? Where you put `clickListener`?

Comment: Post your logcat.

Comment: btnSubmit works. yeah! Not sure why btnDifferent doesn't?

Comment: From where you set the listen? I don't see that part at all

Comment: You are not extending the View.OnClickListener interface and no click listener for the button

Comment: @JohnB, You used the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58527690/2637449. But not accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code.

1. Implement `View.OnClickListener` to `Activity`
2. set `onClick` listener to `btnDifferent` in `onCreate()`. like `btnDifferent.setOnClickListener(this)`. OR if you are setting listener from XML, then make sure you have added same code for `btnDifferent`

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement `View.OnClickListener` to Activity
2. set `onClick` listener to `btnDifferent` in `onCreate()` method like

```
 btnDifferent.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Comment: too much of copy paste

Comment: Where in the onCreate() method should I place it?

Answer (score 0):

**Option - 1:** You have to implements `View.OnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnDifferent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDifferent);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDifferent.setOnClickListener(this);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int index1 = spnCurrency1.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int index2 = spnCurrency2.getSelectedItemPosition();
        float value = Float.parseFloat(from.getText().toString());

        float ratio[] = {0.9f, 1.0f, 0.78f};
        float result = value / ratio[index1] * ratio[index2];

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSubmit:
                to.setText(result + "");
                break;
            case R.id.btnDifferent:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Result", result);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option - 2:** You have to call `onClick` with appropriate view

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnDifferent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDifferent);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick(v);
        }
    });

    btnDifferent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onClick(v);
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

**Option - 3:** If you call `onClick` from xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/android_list_view_tutorial_with_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--android:onClick="onClick" should be same-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDifferent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button Different" />

    <!--android:onClick="onClick" should be same-->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. That just seems to crash the application? I see that the OnClickListener's have been implemented, but does that suffice in helping the OnClick method connect

Comment: do you call onClick from xml?